# 'end up to find' or "end up finding"? Gerund vs Infinitive?

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund, to-infinitive

What is the reason for using "finding" in this sentence and not "to find"?
"These newcomers often end up not (to find)/(finding) the opportunities they are looking for."

Comment: If you try to say the sentence without the negative you'll see that only the gerund makes sense. (Perhas someone else will provide an answer addressing the actual grammar).

Comment: I am not sure that there is a reason beyond "because that is the way English is."  You can *try to find* X, or *start to find* X, but you can only *continue finding* X or *end up finding* X.  But it would be great if someone could prove me wrong and show that there is a specific rule!

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it more, *continue to find* is OK too.  But "end up to find" still sounds weird.

Answer (score 1):

> These newcomers often end up not to find the opportunities they are looking for.

> These newcomers often end up not finding the opportunities they are looking for.

The second example is fine; the first is not.

'*end up*' is a phrasal verb, and its use in this context, according to the respective notations of the two dictionaries shown below, is [ + -ing verb ] or [VERB PARTICLE verb-ing].

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/end-up

> — phrasal verb with end verb [ I or T ]

> to finally be in a particular place or situation:

> [ + -ing verb ] After working her way around the world, she ended up teaching English as a foreign language.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/end-up

If you don't know what you want, you might end up getting something you don't want. [VERB PARTICLE verb-ing]

An Ngram search for these two usage forms, *end up to find* and *end up finding*, gets nothing for the former.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=End+up+to+find%2Cend+up+finding&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cend%20up%20finding%3B%2Cc0

Edit after Comments from @BillJ

The verb *end up* is a catenative verb here.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb

> [C]atenative verbs are verbs which can be followed within the same clause by another verb. This second subordinated verb can be in either the infinitive (both full and bare) or gerund form.

> Some catenative verbs are followed by a to-infinitive: "He agreed to work on Saturday"

> Some catenative verbs are followed by a gerund: "He admitted taking the money".

Of the two categories shown above, the verb *end up* belongs to the second one.

Comment: The grammatical answer is that the catenative verb "end up" licenses gerund-participial clauses, but not infinitival ones.